# "Dibs" im Deutschen?

Tags: colloquial, phrase-request, english-to-german

Im Englischen gibt es den Ausdruck "to have dibs on sth.", auch einfach als Ausruf "Dibs!" gebraucht, der bedeutet, dass man ein Vorrecht auf eine bestimmte Sache beansprucht. "Dibs" ist ein Wort der Umgangssprache und wird oft (aber nicht ausschließlich) von Kindern und Jugendlichen benutzt.

Eine Besonderheit ist, dass mit dem Ausruf "Dibs!" tatsächlich ein "moralischer Anspruch" des Ausrufers auf die Sache entsteht, der dann von den "unterlegenen" Parteien oft ohne weiteres akzeptiert wird.

Ich suche ein Gegenstück im Deutschen, das möglichst ebenso sparsam und universell einsetzbar ist.

Beispiele:

> Person 1: "There's one piece of cake left."
>
> Person 2: "Dibs!"
>
> Person 3: "Damn!"

Informell gibt es die Formulierung auch im Geschäftsleben:

> CTO: "When new laptops are purchased, the design department has dibs on them."

Dieser [Clip aus der TV-Serie "How I Met Your Mother"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wEB2cgDhwU) ist ebenfalls eine gute Dokumentation der Nutzung von "dibs".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibs) listet als vergleichbaren Begriff im Deutschen "Erster!" auf, mir fiele sonst noch "Meins!" ein - beide sind in meinen Augen aber kein vollwertiger Ersatz, weil sie

- zu sehr die Konnotation streitender Kinder mit sich tragen
- nicht gleichermaßen universell einsetzbar sind: "Meins!" funktioniert bei Sachen, die man sich nehmen kann, "Erster!" hauptsächlich bei Reihenfolgen
- nicht die konfliktlösenden Eigenschaften von "dibs" mitbringen: Der Ausruf "Dibs!" markiert eher das Ende eines Streits (oder verhindert dessen Beginn), "Meins!" und "Erster!" dagegen laden viel eher zum Widerspruch ein.

Comment: Alles, was ich über "dibs" geschrieben habe, ist meine eigene Wahrnehmung als Nicht-Muttersprachler. Liebe Englisch-Muttersprachler, bitte korrigiert mich falls ich mit meiner Interpretation falsch liege.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, das "dibs" wirklich einen "moralischen Anspruch" mit sich bringt. Jedenfalls nicht mehr als "Wer will noch ein Stück Kuchen?" - "Ich!" - "Nichts da, Du hattest schon fünf." ;-)

Comment: Mir ist leider keine bessere Formulierung eingefallen... Es scheint aber jedenfalls so zu sein, dass der Ruf "Dibs!" ausreicht, um das gewünschte Anrecht tatsächlich zu bekommen.

Comment: Bei identischer Ausgangsposition (z.B. wer im Auto vorne sitzen darf oder wer als einziger ein zweites Stück Pizza bekommt). Ich denke, das bei ungleicher Ausgangsposition (z.B. ein Mitfahrer mit Gipsbein, ein später Dazugekommener der noch gar keine Pizza hatte) ein "Dibs!" durchaus "disputed" werden kann. Mag mich aber irren; mir ist der Begriff zwar geläufig, habe ihn aber nie mit "Einheimischen" durchdiskutiert.

Comment: Geht mir genauso - "meine Bildung hab ich aus dem Fernseh'n" ;-) Könnte mir aber gut vorstellen, dass man im Falle eines Gipsbeins o.ä. einfach nicht "dibs" sagt. Man tut es einfach nicht.

Comment: Ist also letztendlich eine Frage der Moral - sowohl das Einräumen eines "Dibs" (das macht man halt so) wie auch das Verzichten auf ein "Dibs" wenn die Situation klar ist. Meiner Wahrnehmung nach wird die "Unumstößlichkeit" eines "Dibs" vor allem von solchen "Typen" propagiert, die sich so ihren Ellenbogeneinsatz "kulturell schönreden" möchten.

Comment: @Jan: Ich bestätige Deine Interpretation (als Nicht-Muttersprachler). Ist aber nicht verwunderlich; ich kenne Dibs auch nur aus HIMYM. Und vielleicht ist das auch ein Problem. Vielleicht sollte jemand mal bei EL&U nachfragen, ob die Situationen im realen Leben auch wie in der Serie ausgehen. Also dass Dibs von beiden Parteien allgemein akzeptiert wird.

Comment: @musiKk: gute Idee - ich hab mal eine [Frage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43685/calling-dibs-what-does-it-imply) gepostet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wie du in der Frage bereits erwähnt hast, ist der englische Ausdruck "dibs!" (oder "I claim dibs on...") ein Slang-Ausruf, mit dem jemand Anspruch auf etwas erhebt.

Ich finde, dass "dibs!" durchaus einen kindlichen Charakter hat, was in der Fernsehserie HIMYM immer wieder durchscheint.

Also:

> Meins!

finde ich auch wegen der phonetischen Ähnlichkeit am besten geeignet. In geeigneten Fällen, bei denen es sich um eine Tätigkeit handelt, ist vielleicht als Übersetzung

> Erste(r)!

besser geeignet.

Dieselbe Bedeutung hat auch aus der Ausruf

> (Für mich) reserviert!

Außerdem hört man auch im Deutschen "Dibs!" oder "Shotgun!" immer häufiger. Ich glaube, dass sie sich in ein paar Jahren sich einbürgern könnten.

Comment: +1 für "Shotgun!" ;)

Comment: Im Auto: "Erster Vorne-Sitzer!" (Optional: "Ohne Streit!")

Comment: Was soll HIMYM sein?

Comment: @harper How I Met Your Mother

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe für diesen Ausdruck schon des öfteren die deutsche Wendung

> Erster ohne Streit!

gehört, vor allem unter Kindern.

Der Comic **Werner** verwendet diese Wendung auch immer wieder.

Answer (score 1):

Ich erinnere mich, dass in meiner Grundschulzeit in vergleichbaren Fällen oft der Ausdruck "Leo" verwendet wurde, z.B. wenn es beim Sport oder bei Spielen darum ging, wer den Ball annehmen wollte. Das wurde dann auch nicht in Frage gestellt oder gar diskutiert, soweit ich mich erinnern kann.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Ansicht nach existiert ein solcher Begriff mit der von Dir eingeforderten *konfliktlösenden Eigenschaft* im Deutschen schlichtweg nicht. Es mag eine in den USA weitverbreitete *Konvention* sein, aber in Deutschland dürfte so etwas allenfalls in kleineren "Biotopen" der Fall sein. In manchen Sportarten mag es gelten - da besteht dann auch größerer Bedarf, weil 2 Mannschaftskameraden logischerweise nicht erst ausdiskutieren können, wer den Ball annimmt - und in einzelnen Familien oder in Kindergruppen mag es so gehandhabt werden, aber Allgemeingültigkeit hat es definitiv nicht. Ich gucke kein HIMYM, und mir war der Begriff "Dibs" bis gestern völlig unbekannt - ich hätte einen eventuelle Dibs-Rufer völlig verständnislos angeguckt; und hätte er mir dann erklärt, dass derjenige, der das zuerst ruft, einen unanfechtbaren Anspruch auf das fragliche Objekt habe, hätte ich entgegnet, dass ich mich beim besten Willen nicht erinnern könne, einer solchen Vereinbarung zugestimmt zu haben.